# How to handle off-topic questions with a bounty

Tags: discussion, off-topic, bounty

Second question that I recall in recent weeks where the question is completely off topic and the OP posted a bounty before it was closed: [Select Google music track on Android to play via Nexus Play/Fire TV/Apple TV -> AV receiver](https://superuser.com/questions/950232/select-google-music-track-on-android-to-play-via-nexus-play-fire-tv-apple-tv).  This is about using an Android phone to play music from an online library through a home audio system.

By the time the bounty is up, the three existing close votes are likely to be expired.  It seems like it would be in the OP's interest to migrate the question to where it belongs.  Does the bounty prevent the question from being properly handled?

Comment: I saw that one. I already flagged it before I saw this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention, and in the "other" box state that it's off-topic but you can't close it because of the bounty. If a moderator deems it to be off-topic, they will remove the bounty and close the post.

Comment: Does "remove the bounty" regains the lost rep?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, it refunds the rep to whoever offered the bounty.

Comment: What if the bounty has already been awarded to another user, and after that event, the question is made off-topic and closed/migrated?