# What's the reasoning behind not allowing questions with active bounties to be closed?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the list of questions with active bounties I found [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1016525/is-there-a-better-library-third-party-software-spell-checker-for-mac-that-can-gu), which in my opinion is off-topic because the OP is seeking advice/third party software. I was about to flag it for closing, but a message was shown saying this question couldn't be closed as it has an active bounty.

I found [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9609/how-to-handle-off-topic-questions-with-a-bounty) on meta about how to handle off-topic questions with a bounty, and the [answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/9613/307878) says it should be flagged for moderator attention.

What's the reasoning behind not allowing users to vote to close the ones that are against the SuperUser policy? I mean, I know we can notify moderators, right? But wouldn't it be *easier* to vote these questions directly without moderator intervention and at the same time save them from doing some additional work? After all, several close votes would still be needed to actually close the question and remove the bounty.

Comment: The primary reason would be the attempt to protect the user rewarding the bounty to the question from being unable to award the bounty, since questions which are closed, cannot have new answers.  Since a bounty only lasts for I believe 7 days, once the question is promoted, it would receive a great more attention then it originally did.  **The question's author in this case, clearly saw the pending close votes (3), and issued the bounty.**  Which only makes me want to bring the question to the attention of the moderators, so it can be closed faster, since the question is clearly not on topic.

Comment: I already did and the question seems to be now on hold - however, I still think 5 votes would be protection enough for the user awarding the bounty (it doesn't mean I'm right though :-)), after all, that's what the review system on the SE community is based on.

Comment: You asked for the possible reason.  If you want to know the real reason, asking at meta.stackexchange would allow for a developer to respond or explain the specific reason.

Comment: The reason is probably the bounty, itself.  I believe a moderator can cancel the bounty and close the question.  If it's just voted on, the OP would lose the bounty because it's normally considered "non-refundable".